# How to animate individual elements in ListView

Tags: android, listview, animation

I'm doing a small Android app based around a ListView. When the user selects one or more elements in the list and subsequently selects a menu item from the ActionBar I would like to do a small animation on the selected elements in the list, and this is where things go wrong.

Nothing animates - nor does anything fail. The following code piece is a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
private void animateListViewItem()
{
    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
    anim.setDuration(2000);
    View v = fragment.getListAdapter().getView(fragment.getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition(), null, null);
    v.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

When I messed around with it, trying to figure out what was wrong, I at one point substituted the item with the entire ListView to rule out the animation as the source of the problem - like this.

```
private void animateListViewItem()
{
    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
    anim.setDuration(2000);
    fragment.getListView().startAnimation(anim);
}
```

To my amazement, that worked perfect!

So my question is - why can't I animate the individual elements in a ListView? Or is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

P.S. For the record the ListView is populated with custom views (LinearLayouts), and I have checked that I get the right item before animating.

Comment: Sorry, I have little experience with animations or view manipulation. Have you tried this though:
    View v = fragment.getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition();

Comment: If you look at the first code example, that is exactly what I am doing there... And while it gives me the view I am looking for - that view will not animate - and I do not understand why

Comment: Good first posts (question and answer). They are clear, detailed, and if there were errors you stated that you would posted the logcat trace; wish more members were as thorough as you. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Slind I a working on the same issue..can u tell me whatis fragment here...can u please show ur code......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out what the issue was:

```
View v = fragment.getListAdapter().getView(fragment.getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition(), null, null);
```

This line was the problem. It returns a *new* `View` to display the underlying data at the specified position in the list not the *existing* `View`. So the returned `View` has nothing to do with the list.

Instead doing this:

```
View v = fragment.getListView().getChildAt(fragment.getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition());
```

Got me the `View` that the list was using and the animation worked as expected.

Comment: As a side note, this is the same reason why my views did not have any dimensions when I checked for properties like getX getY etc. I was looking at a dummy view, and not the real view

Comment: @Slind can u please tell me about, what is fragment here and from where i should call the animateListViewItem() method for animating individual items

Comment: @Anshuman THe fragment is just because I am working in a fragment and not an Activity. If you are in a ListActivity, just replace fragment.getListView() with getListView() and the rest should be the same. By the way, place remember that this is a simplified example. Since ListView reuses Views, you should adjust the position according to what View is the FirstVisible View in the list.