# Android listview firstscreen's item animation no effect

Tags: android, listview, animation

I have a `listview` in an activity, each `listview` item have a `viewswitcher` and there are two child view in `viewswitcher`. I set the viewswitcher's `android:inAnimation` and `android:outAnimation` property in layout xml. When I run the app, I find that the listview's fristscreen have no animation effect when the `viewswitcher` switch its child view , but the other item witch no in the fristscreen have animation effect .

What cause this problem? How to fix it?

Comment: I find when I click fristscreen's item,it call getview() two itmes.When call getView() second time may break the frist time animation.Why system call getView() two times.

Comment: Check this Question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903364/how-to-animate-individual-elements-in-listview?rq=1